# Jetpack Compose performance issues with dynamic height composables

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

Let's say i want to make a lazy row with Cards, the content of the card defines it's minimal height.

[You can find a simple figma example here](https://www.figma.com/file/YNJbYKDIG6rgkgRkEeJ2mz/Untitled?type=design&node-id=1-2&mode=design&t=SLNYcVkBEVW1fZBQ-4), i will use this example as reference.

I want all the cards to be as high as the highest card (`215px` in the example). Ofcourse we can only get the height of the currently visible items because we are loading them `lazy`.

This means is that the cards with a height of `195px`, `125px` and `160px` need to fill and also be `215px` high (to reach the black line).

What are the possibilities to make all the cards as high as the highest item, without causing to much redrawing and/or calculations?

Currently i am running in performance issues when i use `.onGlobalyPositioned` to calculate and save the height of the highest element and afterwards redraw the row with this height.

Would like to hear your ideas and vision in this matter.